# SWIFT BLE for Blood KETONE data from Glucose Sensor not specified in Bluetooth documentation?

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am trying to distinguish ketone and glucose data from a blood glucose meter but GATT does not specify anything regarding blood ketone data.

https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml

https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.glucose.xml

```
[3, 0, 0, 228, 7, 5, 23, 14, 28, 0, 0, 0, 103, 176, 17] <- glucose 5.7 mmol/L

[3, 1, 0, 228, 7, 5, 23, 14, 28, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 17]

[3, 2, 0, 228, 7, 5, 23, 14, 18, 0, 0, 0, 55, 176, 17] <- ketose 1.8 mmol/L

[3, 3, 0, 228, 7, 5, 23, 14, 18, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 17]

[3, 4, 0, 228, 7, 3, 14, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0, 112, 176, 17] <- glucose 6.2 mmol/L

[3, 5, 0, 228, 7, 3, 14, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 17]

[3, 6, 0, 228, 7, 3, 10, 13, 49, 0, 0, 0, 13, 176, 17] <- ketose 0.4 mmol/L 

[3, 7, 0, 228, 7, 3, 10, 13, 49, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 17]
```

Comment: Could this be a proprietary protocol? There always seem to appear two samples at once. The first one has a reasonable value. But in the second on, the *sfloat* is always 0xffff. Neither the two samples with the same time stamp nor the value of the second one seem right.

Comment: Is this the only characteristic? Or is there another one for Ketone?

Comment: @Codo It must be a proprietary protocol as bluetooth has nothing about ketose services. These are the services.  https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.glucose.xml I checked with the LightBlue app and the only services that show are 0x2A18, 0x2A34, 0x2A51, 0x2A52

Comment: @Codo I found a way to calculate the correct ketose value, but I cannot distinguish the ketose/glucose data from each other as it is sent over the same characteristic. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: I can only think of the sequence number to distinguish them. The two LSB might indicate what was measured. This might also be the reason for the filler samples with 255, 255.

Comment: What exact brand and model for blood glucose meter do you have anyway?